# How to create database link to access dba tables from another user

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

How to create database link to access dba tables from another user (which has no dba rights)?  I want to take back up of sys.aud$ table in another tablespace which belongs to a user, but I am unable to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to create a link. You my just grant select on this table/view to any user or create view and grant select on view. eg:

```
connect sys/<pass> as sysdba 

grant select on sys.aud$ to NON_DBA_USER;
```

or create view with some restrictions:

```
create view view_to_grant_with_rest as select * from sys.aud$ where rownum < 11; 

grant select on view_to_grant_with_rest to NON_DBA_USER;
```

Comment: are you run `create view sys.aud$2` from sys user? Could you provide an erro text?